# Rails: refresh token for vkontakte

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, token, omniauth, vk

How to refresh(update) access token for already connected Vkontakte provider (connected via omniauth)?

So, at my DB I have object with fields like this:

> id: integer, provider: string, uid: string, user_id: integer, token:
>   string, expires_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at:
>   datetime, type: string, reset_at: datetime, refresh_token: string,
>   refreshed_at: datetime, root_id: integer, refreshed: boolean

What kind of request should I do to get new token and update my provider object at DB ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you do not need to refresh access token, since when you request 'offline' access the token lifetime is forever (expires=0)